# Trouble linking CSS stylesheet to HTML in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I've formatted my base page properly and I have used the correct tags in my `HTML` pages, yet my local `css` file (`main.css`) will not load.

base.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% block script %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/07a07b3c8d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <title>{% block title %}Edward's Portfolio{% endblock %}</title>
    <style>
        body {
          font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
        }
    </style>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Settings.py:

```
    from pathlib import Path
    import os.path

    # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'PortfolioApp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL= "/media/"
```

Here is the structure of my static folder:

[image: Static/css/main.css]

I have set my `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` correctly in `settings.py` but I have still found no success. If I could get some assistance I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you set your temples DIR?

Comment: @AaronCloud I've set the template DIR correctly

Comment: What is the structure of your statics folder ? The files tree in that folder.

Comment: @B.Okba Check the edit I made

Comment: To make sure about everything, please include your settings of static and the urls. Also what are you getting when you visit this: http://localhost:8000/static/css/main.css ?

Comment: @B.Okba It's saying "Page not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your trying to do this with DEBUG=True you also need to set STATICFILES_DIR

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

If you can post your settings.py with ALL of these set wecan help.

STATIC_ROOT is used in production, with DEBUG to False and you run
`python manage.py collectstatic`. So if your in production and having this issue you first need to set the urls for django to serve static files

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

then run the command `python manage.py collectstatic`

A quick example for specifying static directory in production/dev (DEBUG=True/False)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = BASE_DIR / 'static' # this is a top-level static directory (same level as manage.py), you can create a list of dirs if you have static files in each app. This value is checked DEBUG=True
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static' # this value is checked in production
```

Comment: You dont have STATICFILES_DIRS set like mentioned above. We need to know if the code is being run locally or in production, either way I have provided a solution for both.

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked! Thank you a lot

Comment: Sure no problem. You can name the static directory to be anything you want. Just make sure you set the value to the correct constant. Some people use "staticfile".

Answer (score 0):

Update your static settings like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = f'{BASE_DIR}{STATIC_URL}'
STATICFILES_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [f'{BASE_DIR}{STATICFILES_URL}',]
```

And inside urls.py, write this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
# After urlpatterns
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then rename your **static** folder to **staticfiles**